# Раздвижной плагин

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Помогите найти плагин, как на сайте http://fast-torrent.ru/. В меню есть кнопка "Другие жанры", по нажатию на неё раздвигаются дополнительные жанры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ul>
<li>lalala</li>
<li>lalala</li>
<li class="showmore">show more</li>
<li>lalala</li>
<li>lalala</li>
<li>lalala</li>
<li>lalala</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('ul .showmore').nextAll('li').hide();
    $('ul .showmore').click(function(){
        $(this).nextAll('li').show().end().remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

Эффект появления можно поменять. Используется jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Собственно, в чём сложность? Прячете скрытые элементы в блок, а по клику на "другие жанры" делаете slideDown() - если на jQuery.
Вот схематически:

```
<!-- разметка -->
<li id="clickMe">Другие жанры</li>
<div class="hideClass" id="showMe">
    ...
    <li>жанр</li>
    <li>жанр</li>
    ...
</div>

/* CSS */
.hideClass{ display: none;}

/* jQuery script */
$("#clickMe").click(function(){
    $(".hideClass").slideDown("fast").show();//Показали список
    $(this).hide();//Спрятали пункт "другие жанры"
});
```

Comment: Дело в том что в js я 0, и писать / дополнять меню тоже не в состоянии) по этому прошу полную заготовку меню

Comment: Заготовки привели я и товарищ @ling - пользуйтесь!  
А раз вы не можете **даже** дополнять меню - может сперва стоит разобраться с версткой, и уже потом лезть в скрипты? ИМХО, разумеется.

Comment: так у меня есть сайт и на нем движок который я написал сам))но единственое он без js, ну вот допустим код товарища @ling я скопировал вставил в html, вывелось все то что в li.. просто тупо вывелось, наверное нужно подключить какую то библиотеку? или что?

Comment: В обоих ответах написано, что нужно подключать [jQuery][1]


  [1]: http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery